# How to make language switching in Vue i18n

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a Vue application that the i18n library is connected to. have jason with translations. One page - one JSON, in which all the translations. JSON looks like this:

```
{"en-En":{"same text":"same text","same text":"same text"},
"de-De":{"same text":"gleicher Text","same text":"gleicher Text"}}}
```

all translations are loaded first in multistoreLanguages.json and from there already to the site

```
 if (extName === '.json') { 
          if (directory.indexOf('theme-default/resource/i18n') != -1){
          const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')
          const fileJsonObject = JSON.parse(fileContent)
         Object.keys(fileJsonObject).forEach((languagesJson) => {
              console.log(languagesJson, 'languagesJson')
              messages[languagesJson] = Object.assign(messages[languagesJson] ? messages[languagesJson] : {}, fileJsonObject[languagesJson])             

          }
```

i18n.json looks like

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en', 
    fallbackLocale: 'de'   
});

export default i18n;
```

All text is connected to the library. How do I switch between languages?

Comment: Does their recommendation in their documentation not work? https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html

Comment: no, it does not work